# Facing problem with MP4 file uploads on Ubuntu with filezilla (the file size reduces after upload). Can someone help?

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, mp4, filezilla

I am attempting to upload an mp4 file (112MB) to a Linux server. After a successful transfer, its size is reduced to 103MB or 80MB. It is not uploading the full size. Its Owner/Group changed automatically into root/root as well.

I've also enabled the `lsyncd` service. It works great after you stop the service. I reviewed the `lsyncd` logs but found nothing.

Can anybody help me out? I also checked `lsyncd` logs, but nothing was found. I checked the transfer mode in FileZilla, and its set to Auto mode.

I tried changing the transfer mode to Binary from auto. I also checked the logs, but everything is normal and upon checking the `lsyncd` config, I did not find any issue. Also, we can't stop the `lsyncd` service every time we upload as there are lots of files to be transferred This issue started to happen recently.

Comment: "After a successful transfer, its size is reduced to 103MB or 80MB. " is this between windows and linux? or another filesystem? make sure its the same unit and not MB and MiB

Comment: du -h filename shows the size in kiB/MiB/GiB (1024 increments) and du -h --si filename shows the size in kB/MB/GB (1000 increments)

Comment: 1. Can you check md5sum or sha256sum of the original file and of the copy in the server? They should match.; 2. Please tell us about the operating systems (and versions) in the Linux server and the client computer; 3. Tell us also about the connection. What network is it (local or via the internet)?

Comment: sudodus I am using the internet for the file transfer. I am transferring the files from windows 11 pro 22H2 laptop to the Ubuntu 18.04. After completing the file transfer, the size of the file changes automatically as I can see the size on both local machine and server side in FileZilla. The file size is in MB. As I mentioned if I stop the lsyncd service and then transfer the file, there is no change in the size but if I transfer the file while the lsyncd service is running, the size changes.

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to what is described in the paragraph '2-way/bidirection synchronization': https://github.com/lsyncd/lsyncd#2-waybidirection-synchronization.

Comment: There is one way sync going on currently from the directory on one Ubuntu machine to the another one with the same specs i,e Only one source to one target. The paragraph2 is pointing out an issues with 2 way sync, which we have not implemented.